# authentication error for accessing data product on scihub through wget

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-1, copernicus

I am new to Sentinel(overall remote sensing domain) and currently trying to download the data products from Scihub using the wget utility on Windows10 machine. However I am getting the below error. I have verified that my credentials are correct by logging in to the Scihub portal separately.

Command:
`wget --no-check-certificate --user={*MYUSERNAME*} --password={*MYPASSWORD*} --output-document=query_results.txt "https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/search?q=ingestiondate:[NOW-1DAY TO NOW] AND producttype:SLC&rows=100&start=0&format=json"`

Error:
--2018-07-27 14:47:26--  https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/search?q=ingestiondate:[NOW-1DAY%20TO%20NOW]%20AND%20producttype:SLC&rows=100&start=0&format=json

Resolving scihub.copernicus.eu (scihub.copernicus.eu)... 131.176.236.28
Connecting to scihub.copernicus.eu (scihub.copernicus.eu)|131.176.236.28|:443... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized Authentication selected: Basic realm="Sentinels Scientific Data Hub Search"
Reusing existing connection to scihub.copernicus.eu:443.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized

Username/Password Authentication Failed.

Can anyone suggest what am I missing here?

Comment: do you have spaces or any weird escape characters in your username or password? I find some generated passwords can't be used easily on the linux/mac command line as the shell interprets some character combinations, I imagine it's the same on Windows. And spaces will definitely break the command.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to resolve this issue. The problem was with parenthesis surrounding the username and password. They need to be put in double-quotes ("). 
Hope this helps anyone facing same issue in future.

Cheers!